# Testing for Significance - Should t-test be used or paired t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, inference

Let's say there are 100 stock exchanges on which I trade stocks and the cost of me trading has the averages below

```
            Average Cost to Trade
Exchange1    .23
Exchange2    .34
Exchange3    .10
....
.....
Exchange100    .025
```

Someone asks me "Are those numbers statistically significant"?

Each average is calculated from the distribution of costs on each exchange.

I was thinking of doing 100 t-tests with the null hypothesis that the mean is 0 and alternative that the mean is not 0. If the p-value < .05 then I'd conclude the means are significant.

Is that the approach to take when trying to answer "Are those numbers statistically significant"?

Should I be doing paired t-test?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not try a one-way ANOVA?

Comment: @missingdataguy  The ANOVA would only determine that there is a difference between exchanges, but doesn’t tell which is
different  whereas the t-test would identify which exchanges the cost is not significant

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you should phrase your question avoiding the word "significant", which often gets in the way of clear thinking.

You propose to test the null hypothesis that the mean of reach exchange is zero. But you know for sure that the cost is never zero, so why test that?

Is your goal to ask whether there is evidence that different exchanges have different costs? Do you need data to answer that? Aren't the costs specified up front? If you do need to test with data, you'd need multiple values from each exchange. Then you could run one-way ANOVA to ask if there is evidence that the average costs are not all the same. I doubt that question is really of interest.

Comment: The cost is the cost of trading not the fee posted to trade. So the cost can be 0.  Each one of those average comes from a distribution of costs where some are positive and some are negative and some are 0.              My goal is to answer "are the average costs meaningful"?  I used "statistically significant" because that is what I've read. Wouldn't an anova just say "the cost are different" but it wouln't identify which costs are differnent.  So wouldn't I use a t-test with null= 0 to say the cost is not zero?

Comment: (+1 to this answer.) An ANOVA can tell you much more than that, by using "post-hoc" and "planned comparison" tests.  You can get a good start by searching [HSD](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=HSD), the name of a particular *post hoc* test. It's still not clear what your research question is, though. *Of course* costs are meaningful! Perhaps you are asking whether and when you should treat differences among previous costs as being reliable indicators of the cost differences to expect over a long future?

Comment: My question is "are the cost significant". I define "significant" as different from 0.

Comment: How can the cost of trading be negative?

Comment: And are the pricing strategies of the different exchanges a secret? Do you really need to compare with data? Can't you just compare algorithms?

Fidelity charges 8 dollars per trade. ETrade charges 10 dollars per trade. I don't need statistical analysis of data to know which one is less expensive!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will use ANOVA to state if there are differences and then use TUKEY HSD to identify which pairwise differences are significant. Sound right? Thank you.